# How to create slide in/out panels using Bootstrap 3 collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an effect with Bootstrap 3 and the collapse plugin where the content panels always slide up when hidden, and slide down when revealed.

The complication comes in that the content panels slide into/out of the same space and the collapse/accordion effect makes it look like the panel being replaced is sliding down, depending on its position in the panel group.

**HTML**

```
<div class="caseStudyContent collapse" id="caseStudyContent-0">
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 caseStudyContentCol">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla elementum, magna ac aliquet sagittis, quam nisi blandit purus, ac dapibus neque odio quis urna. Maecenas tristique euismod diam, nec pellentesque tortor dignissim at. Donec in quam ut nisl suscipit gravida. Integer eget finibus sem. Sed rutrum vehicula faucibus. Ut molestie nunc ac neque dapibus, eu tristique enim malesuada. Donec nec cursus odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus lorem dolor, dapibus ut felis dignissim, porta mattis tellus.</p>
            <a class="closeCaseStudy">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="caseStudyContent collapse" id="caseStudyContent-1">
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 caseStudyContentCol">
            <p>Ut porta luctus lobortis. Pellentesque pellentesque tempus ex, a ultrices justo mollis ac. Curabitur at luctus quam, et sagittis justo. Fusce eget euismod leo. Donec blandit est vulputate tincidunt ullamcorper. Morbi ultrices luctus massa, ac rutrum lectus aliquam non. Suspendisse dapibus consectetur arcu, et convallis dui porttitor vehicula. Vestibulum pulvinar pellentesque tempor. Fusce feugiat fermentum egestas. Cras in tristique tellus, nec consequat arcu.</p>
            <a class="closeCaseStudy">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="caseStudyContent collapse" id="caseStudyContent-2">
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 caseStudyContentCol">
            <p>Morbi vulputate consectetur lorem, eget ultricies risus hendrerit eget. Duis tempus sapien ac mi consectetur sollicitudin. Fusce porta lorem mi, ac dignissim neque tincidunt vel. Ut eget nisl sed arcu aliquam facilisis a a magna. Maecenas et tempus lectus. Aenean ultricies sit amet diam eu sagittis. Nullam et odio tellus. Etiam sit amet arcu nec mi auctor feugiat quis nec ligula. Nullam id euismod purus. Ut nec pretium enim. Fusce lorem sapien, ullamcorper in nisi ut, pulvinar fermentum nisl. Phasellus tortor neque, porttitor vitae massa sollicitudin, varius bibendum diam. Maecenas ultricies finibus justo id dictum. Maecenas nunc libero, malesuada eget volutpat quis, elementum at mauris. Proin luctus posuere metus, vitae posuere est feugiat sed.</p>
            <a class="closeCaseStudy">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.closeCaseStudy').on('click',function(){$('.in').collapse('hide');})
$('.caseStudyButton').on('click',function(){$('.in').collapse('hide');})
```

I've created a jsfiddle here that demonstrates the interaction that I'm trying to achieve, while showcasing that the transition looks deeply odd : http://jsfiddle.net/6h6g8qce/

Ideally, what I'd like to do is to somehow get hide.bs.collapse to **always** trigger a slideUp while show.bs.collapse **always** triggers a slideDown.

I also wonder if it's possible to delay the show.bs.collapse of other elements until hidden.bs.collapse occurs, so there's a smooth slide out, then slide in?

Comment: See this doc http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: That's how I got it working this far already, see the jsfiddle - The above code works in so far as it collapses and reveals panels. It doesn't work in that it's got an animation effect designed for an accordion - so when the first item is open,  and the second item is clicked, the first item slides **down** to collapse. While that's great behaviour for an accordion, it looks super odd in the layout I've come up with.